# Rookie wants to send email from a web page

Tags: javascript, email

I'm just hoping you can point me in the right direction. I know Javascript (pretty well, but I do NOT use JQuery, fyi) and have a site where I want folks to fill out a few fields, including their email address, and click send and it will automatically send me an email.

What's the best contemporary solution for this? Do I need to learn PHP for this perhaps?

Any input greatly appreciated :)
Dan P.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](http://emailjs.com?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclaimer - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can approach this:

1. Learn some server code (PHP works but NodeJS with ExpressJS may be easier if you already know JS) and send yourself an email from your own server.
2. You can let the browser use the default email app to let the user manually send an email with the details filled in `<a href="mailto:mail@example.com">Send an Email </a>`.
3. You can use a third party mail service like [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) and [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) which provide REST API support. You can trigger an AJAX request from the browser to trigger the API with the fields provided by the user. (You can also club this with point 1 and use these on your server as well)